# How to resolve the drift around the z-axis in an IMU6050 gyroscope?

Tags: accelerometer, imu, calibration, gyroscope, drift

Using the [IMU6050](https://invensense.tdk.com/products/motion-tracking/6-axis/mpu-6050/) IMU, one can use the accelerometer to calibrate for the drift in x and y rotational axes by applying a complementary filter.

However, I haven't found a way to calibrate for the drift in the z direction. If it's drifting, eventually the situation appears where the axes of x and y are switched, and the program starts to fail.

How to calibrate the drift around the z-axis?

Answer (score 6):

The accelerometer doesn't see changes in gravity when you rotate around the vertical z-axis, so you can't use it as an input for a complementary filter (or any other filter/algorithm) to compensate for z-axis gyroscope drift.

You would need an added compass (magnetometer) for that, which *does* see changes in heading/yaw when you rotate around the z-axis.

The IMU6050 module has an  [MPU6050](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf) on it which doesn't have a magnetometer built in; it only has gyroscopes and accelerometers, so it can't compensate for gyro drift around the z-axis on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount two IMU modules on perpendicular planes - like on the facing pages of an open book. Then you won't need the magnetometer signal, since at least one accelerometer will see changes in gravity as you rotate along *any* axis.

For even better filter performance, you'd want *three* IMUs mounted on faces of a cube, such that the faces share a common vertex.

And, for noise reduction, you could then just keep going and put one IMU on each face of the cube, or even better: rotate the 2nd set of 3-faces 45 degrees away in two axes relative to the first set of 3-faces.

Comment: I can’t see that working - it sounds good in principle but imagine a situation where such a setup is slowly rotating on the z axis - how would it detect this?  You would hope that multiple devices will reduce the drift but it won’t go away completely.